# Present the same `GameScene` again

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

In some tutorial on a paid website I learned that you can replay the game by simply presenting the same scene again but I have no access to that tutorial anymore so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. If I remember correctly, the tutorial used something like this (in `GameScene` class):

```
func newGame() {
    let newScene = GameScene()
    let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithColor(SKColor.blackColor(), duration: 0.5)
        view?.presentScene(newScene, transition: transition)
    view?.presentScene(newScene, transition: transition)
}
```

`GameViewController.swift`:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    if let skView = self.view as? SKView {
        if skView.scene == nil { //if the scene hasn't been created yet
            let aspectRatio = skView.bounds.size.height / skView.bounds.size.width
            let scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: 320, height: 320 * aspectRatio))

            //skView.showsFPS = true
            //skView.showsNodeCount = true
            //skView.showsPhysics = true
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is this gives me the following error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

If I add some breakpoints it seems that the problem is with my `GameScene`. That's first few lines of it:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    var player: Player!
    var world: SKNode!
```

The first and second line are causing an fatal error (I think) but am not sure why. Should I remove all the children from the scene before presenting that same scene again? With that tutorial we just presented the same scene in a few lines and it worked.

**UPDATE:**

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    var player: Player!
    var world: SKNode!

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
        player = Player(position: CGPointMake(size.width*0.5, size.height*0.4))
        world.addChild(player)
    }
}
```

Because the `GameScene` class is quite long, I added just the part which I think is problematic but don't know why or what I should change.

Comment: It looks like the `GameScene` class is assuming that `player` and `world` will be populated. Could you show the full `GameScene` class?

Comment: I added a part of it, I hope it is enough because the whole class is long. If it is not enough I can add additional methods but I think this part is the most relevant.

Comment: New GameScene on each new game seems contradictory with "presenting the same scene again". Something may be wrong in the logic when creating a second instance of GameScene? Hard to tell without more code. Try to construct a "stupid" GameScene and test to be sure that the problem is in GameScene...

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
func newGame() {
    let newScene = GameScene()
    let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithColor(SKColor.blackColor(), duration: 0.5)
        view?.presentScene(newScene, transition: transition)
    view?.presentScene(newScene, transition: transition)
}
```

To this:

```
func newGame() {
    let newScene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: 768, height: 1024))
    let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithColor(SKColor.blackColor(), duration: 0.5)
        view?.presentScene(newScene, transition: transition)
    view?.presentScene(newScene, transition: transition)
}
```

Also with regards to your gameViewController, you don't need to make the size of the skView using the aspect ratio. Since you're using AspectFill as your scaleMode the scene automatically scales it. With this, you would then make the screen size 768x1024 (portrait) or 1024x768 (landscape). To make this compatible with all devices simply make the background 1024x1024 so it looks fine on iPad and you can adjust HUD elements for iPad only by doing something like this:

```
if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
    yourButton.position.y += 100
    yourLabel.position.y += 100
    etc
 }
```